# How to get file from cache file from expo image picker

Tags: react-native, expo

I use Expo Image Picker:  https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/

and after get image from gallery or camera, it return this result:

```
{
  "cancelled":false,
  "height":1611,
  "width":2148,
  "uri":"file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/cropped1814158652.jpg"
}
```

but, what I get is uri only, I need the file, how to get file from that cache uri?

I need to upload that file to server using this

```
module.exports.uploadFile = function(file) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        myServerApi.upload({
            file,
            fileName: file.name, 
        }, function(err, result) {
            if(err) reject(err);
            resolve(result);
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the docs you posted, `ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync(options)`'s `options` have a boolean called `base64`:

> base64 (boolean) -- Whether to also include the image data in Base64 format.

So, following docs example you could do something like:

```
let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
  mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
  allowsEditing: true,
  base64: true, //<-- boolean base64
  aspect: [4, 3],
  quality: 1,
});
```

`result` will be:

```
{
   "cancelled":false,
   "height":1611,
   "width":2148,
   "uri":"file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/cropped1814158652.jpg",
   "base64": "......" //<-- base64 image
}
```

So you can pass `result` to your function `uploadFile` to store image. Something like:

```
result.name = "myImage";
uploadFile(result);
```

Then, as docs say, you could use base64 image also as uri in this way:

> The base64 property is included if the base64 option is truthy, and is a Base64-encoded string of the selected image's JPEG data. If you prepend this with 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' to create a data URI, you can use it as the source of an Image element; for example: <Image source={{uri: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + result.base64}} style={{width: 200, height: 200}} />.